# blank space below footer in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

After so many efforts finally I have designed footer for my website. But whenever I reduce the browser size that is in mobile view I get a blank space below my footer. It is because of the margins added to the content inside footer for desktop view. Also I don't want to change the arrangement of the content inside footer. I tried many things but still not able to get rid of that blank space.

html:

```
<div class="footer" style="font-family: Georgia,Serif;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline" style="margin-left:50px">
        <li><a style="color:white;font-size:20px" href="AboutUs.aspx">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a style="color:white;font-size:20px" href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <p style="color:white;text-align:center;font-size:15px;margin-top:48px">© 2016 Ashwini All Rights Reserved</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <ul class="social-icons icon-circle list-unstyled list-inline" style="float:right">
        <li> <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li> <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li> <a href="http://www.google-plus.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #0E0E0E;
  height:100px;
}
```

[image: Blank space Image]

Comment: is it live? can you post the link of your site instead?...

Comment: No it is not. I am developing it for my project. I have added the image.

Comment: have you tried using `@media`?

Comment: No. I have no idea how to work with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the height for mobile screens.

Also you can align them centrally for mobile.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .footer {
    height: auto;
  }
  .footer ul{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    float: none;
  }
  .footer li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
  }
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/3u3k4v06/

Comment: this does not change anything.. Do I need to override the Bootstrap css or anything?

Comment: I removed the inline style in html.

Comment: now the problem is in mobile view footer is overlapping some part of the content

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, your CSS is currently like this

```
.footer 
{
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0 !important;
left: 0;
padding: 1rem;
background-color: #0E0E0E;
height:100px;
}
```

Where the height of the footer is fixed to 100px.
But your HTML content has three such `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>` divs .Your 3rd row is crossing the 100px threshold.

**Change your min height to a greater value.Better option is to use `%` or `vh`**

```
.footer 
{
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0 !important;
left: 0;
padding: 1rem;
background-color: #0E0E0E;
height:200px;
color:white;
}
```

Here is the working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dexgo195/)

Comment: Thanks I did this. But I dont want to increase the size of footer because it already has less content and increasing more it will look weird.

Comment: I tried this but damn I dont know why that blank space is still showing and the social icons in that space

Comment: @Ashwini, I'm positive that's because of the fixed height.The blank space is that third row, which is messing everything up

Answer (score 1):

You can make `overflow:hidden;`

Working Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKPrEB

```
.footer 
{       
 overflow: hidden;  /*MODIFICATION */
padding-bottom:2px; /*MODIFICATION */
    position: absolute;      
  margin-bottom:0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0 !important;
left: 0;
background-color: #0E0E0E;
height:100px;      
}
```

Comment: Overflow does not work for me. Any idea how can I increase the footer size in mobile view using media?

Comment: @Ashwini just remove padding:1rem and this will stay perfect

Comment: @Ashwini heres working link, i edited the answer too http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZbgPB

Comment: @Ashwini look i edited the answer, see my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105642/discussion-between-ashwini-and-doughnutzombie).

Answer (score 1):

try adding this css will resolve the issue.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   .footer p{
      margin-top:0px !important;
   }
}
```